# Using JQuery, how do I turn a .click() event into something that happens with no user action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working with the following code:

```
$("li.className").click(function () {
  $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0);
});
```

which turns the `<li>` opacity down on click.  How do I make this happen with no user interaction at all, such as when the page loads or after a certain duration of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.className").fadeTo(1000, 0);
})
```

after a duration of time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("li.className").fadeTo(1000, 0);
  }, 2000) // this is 2000ms, or 2seconds
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.click()` on an element without any arguments passed will trigger a click event. (It's shorthand for `.trigger('click')`)

However, it may be a better idea to have a separate function called by your click event and other events, depending on the nature of your code :)

Comment: It's not shorthand for trigger('click'), it's shorthand for bind('click'). Trigger fires an event while bind attaches it to the DOM.

Comment: @Sam152: If you refer to the first paragraph in http://api.jquery.com/click/, you'll see that `.click()` without any arguments passed is equivalent to `.trigger('click')`. I'll add that to the answer :)

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire off this event using the trigger method. All you would have to do is call it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.className").trigger('click');
});
```

Or, if the click event is no longer useful to you you can simply call the fadeTo method directly on the jQuery object like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.className").fadeTo(1000, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it when the page loads, put it in `$(document).ready`. To do it after a certain length of time, put it again in `$(document).ready`, but nest it also within `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0);
}, NUMBER_OF_MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT);
```